# Amana Humidity settings

Tags: dehumidifier

I have a very old Amana dehumidifier.  The setting is a range - Humid - Dry with 5 settings in between.  Can anyone explain would the lowest humidity be "humid" or "dry"

Comment: That's not a setting. It's an indication of what the control does.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Your dehumidifier works to dry out the space, so the closer you are to the "dry" setting the harder it will work to dry things out. That said, small appliance operation is off-topic here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about small appliance operation.